# How to pass parameter from one tab to another tab in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, angular5

As I am new to Ionic 3 I want to know how to pass parameter from one tab to another tab. I am using navCtrl.parent.select(index). I am able to navigate to the other tab but unable to pass the parameter. I am using the following code to achieve this. But failed to retrieve params. 
Thanks in advance for reply

let prm = {
      dt:19,
      month: "November"
    };
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(0).rootParams= prm;

Comment: have a look at ionic docs , they have mentioned about passing data between tabs https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by subscribing to events.

Tab1Component

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

publishEvent() {
  prm = { dt:19, month: "November" };
  this.events.publish('event-name', prm);
}
```

Tab2Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  events.subscribe('event-name', (prm) => {
    console.log(prm);
  });
}
```

I hope it helps